# Vue3:How to pass updated props to child component

Tags: vuejs3, vue-script-setup

I'm trying to figure out how to pass updated props to child component.
For example,

```
// parent component
// temp is an reactive object
<Child :temp="temp">
```

and in Child component,when temp gets modified, the temp props isn't changed.

I'm using script-setup in vue3.

Can you please help me with this issue?

Comment: If you want to change the value of a prop, you need to use emit and change the value in the parent. See https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html

Comment: Can you post also the `Child` component code?

Answer (score 0):

Are you modifying temp in child component? You should avoid manipulation of props.

Otherwise: Are you assigning temp to another variable? It's easy to lose reactivity when doing so, I have learned.

If you provide a little more context your question might get more helpful answers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To see the change, set up a watcher in the child component like this.

```
watch(() => props.temp, (newValue, oldValue) => {
    console.log(props.temp);
});
```

If the variable "temp" changes in the parent component, this watcher should trigger.